# Ubuntu 16.04.1 unable to connect with the ubuntu archive

Tags: 16.04, archive

I cannot download anything. It's always stuck while trying to connect with `ch.archive.ubuntu.com`

```
E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/usb-modeswitch-data_20151101-1_all.deb  Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 kann nicht aufgebaut werden (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]

0% [Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com (130.59.113.36)]
        administrator@ubuntuserver:~$ sudo apt-get update
    OK:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
    Fehl:2 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
      Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 kann nicht aufgebaut werden (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]
    Fehl:3 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
      Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 kann nicht aufgebaut werden (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]
    Fehl:4 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
      Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 kann nicht aufgebaut werden (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]
    Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
    W: Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 kann nicht aufgebaut werden (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]
    W: Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 kann nicht aufgebaut werden (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]
    W: Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Verbindung mit ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 kann nicht aufgebaut werden (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Das Netzwerk ist nicht erreichbar) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]
    W: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

I know it's in German, sorry.

Any ideas?

Comment: Before anything else, change the server. It's probably just a temporary glitch.

Answer (score 0):

My German is bad, so I will answer in English. (ich bin ein anvanger)
Have you confirmed it exists? I had a quick look and I cannot find it.
The archive sites do change and disappear.
You can point your repositories to another archive server.
If you have synaptic package manager installed, fire it up and go over to repositories and untick that archive server.
Also instead of using regional servers, switch to main server, and try again.
If that works for you, choose the next closest regional server.

Hope this helps